# What kind of HD Wallet is used in test rpc?

Tags: testrpc, ethereumjs, hd-wallets

EthereumJS TestRPC starts with a HD Wallet:

```
HD Wallet
==================
Mnemonic:      behave differ train script wedding grant carbon buyer tape make wise soup
Base HD Path:  m/44'/60'/0'/0/{account_index}
```

what implementation is it? can I use it in production?

Answer (score 2):

**DO NOT** use the default mnemonic for production. Everyone has access to that mnemonic and that means they can generate the private keys for all the addresses derived from said mnemonic.

There are several mnemonics generators out there. 
You can even have a combination of a mnemonic and a password for extra security.

https://iancoleman.io/bip39/